# Creating a runnable that uses parameters

Tags: java, constructor, instance, declaration, runnable

I am doing some Android programming and I want to create a runnable that accepts intents. I understand that the general way of creating a runnable is:

**Runnable R1 = new Runnable(){
*Code*
};**

What I want is for my runnable to accept an intention as a parameter or input. The runnable then uses the intention for something else. I imagine that I would look something like this:

**Runnable R1 = new Runnable(Intent i1){
*Code*
};**

I have tried this and variations of this and cannot get it to compile. How do I do this?

Comment: So how do I create the new type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accept parameters, a new class must be created that conforms to Runnable so that the parameters can be passed to (and used usefully in) the constructor. An alternative approach to capture state which is useful with anonymous Runnable objects is to access `final` variables in the lexical scope.

With a new class and a constructor that accepts parameters and stores the values for later use:

```
class RoadRunner implements Runnable {
   String acmeWidget;
   public RoadRunner (string acmeWidget) {
     this.acmeWidget = acmeWidget;
   }
   public void run () {
     evadeCleverPlan(acmeWidget);
   }
}

void doIt () {
  Runnable r = new RoadRunner("Fast Rocket");
  // do something with runnable
}
```

(If `RoadRunner` is an [inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) - that is a non-static nested class - it can also access instance members of the enclosing type.)

With an anonymous Runnable and a "poor man's closure":

```
void doItAnon () {
  final String acmeWidget = "TNT";
  Runnable r = new Runnable () {
    public void run () {
      evadeCleverPlan(acmeWidget);
    }
  };
  // do something with runnable
}
```

(This anonymous Runnable can *also* access instance members of the containing type as [anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) are inner classes.)

Comment: sorry I am not a programmer. I am having a hard time understanding that code. The two snippets of code can both accomplish the task or is the second part of the first?

Comment: They are two different approaches that can both be used, depending on the situation. I would recommend the first approach because it often keeps a cleaner separation of concerns (the 2nd is generally best for things like action handlers). I would recommend following the Java Trail links - understanding how to declare new classes is a vital part of being able to use Java.

Comment: Hey so I have implemented your first solution but I think there is a misunderstanding here. I want to be able to create a runnable once and then pass it different intentions, but this solution requires that I specify the intention when I create the runnable. I have 4 intentions, but I do not want to create 4 runnables for those 4 intentions.

Comment: @jizcoBorneo Do the Runnables do the same thing or different things? If they do the same thing, consider moving the code to a non-inner class (i.e. in it's own .java file) and using the same Runnable class for each of the 4 intentions. When doing this, if the Runnable code needs to access the Intention, pass the Intention as a parameter to the Runnable's constructor and store it as an instance variable for later use (make sure to deal with the Intention lifecycle appropriately). If the Runnables do different things, then they should be different classes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this depends on whether you want to pass in the Intent at the time the Runnable is constructed, or when the run is called. For the former case, user2246674 has provided an excellent answer.

However, if you want to do the latter, you're going to need to create an interface that looks sort of like `Runnable` but isn't.

```
public interface RunnableWithIntent {
  void run(Intent intent);
}
```

You'd then instantiate your "runnable" interface like this:

```
RunnableWithIntent r = new RunnableWithIntent() {
  public void run(Intent intent) {
    // do something with the intent
  }
};
```

And call it like this:

```
Intent intent = ...
r.run(intent);
```

Note that this class can't be used anywhere you would use a regular Runnable object. It merely follows a similar usage pattern.

Comment: So I wont be able to use this with handler.postdelayed?

Comment: No, because in that case you're not calling it - the postDelayed handler is calling it and it won't know anything about your Intent parameter. You would need to use the technique user2246674 suggested: create a Runnable subclass, and pass the Intent parameter to it at the time of construction.